# Post tweet using other accounts using Twiteer4J

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I'm on the second day working with the Twitter API in my application I have an activity that shows the tweets from my account user_timeline using authentication, I am using [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library, everything works fine, but I want to give users the option to be able to tweet my account, and these tweets show up in my `user_timeline` ...

basically the User read my tweets and also can tweet ... I do not know if it was clear.

how do I proceed?

with this code below I post a tweet, however it is published with my User who is authenticated. What I want is to do the same thing but with another user .. (any User to use the app)

```
private void publish(){
           String message="Tweet example";
           try {
               Twitter twitter = ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).getTwitter();

               Status status = twitter.updateStatus(message);
               logger.info("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
           } catch (TwitterException te) {
               te.printStackTrace();
               logger.severe("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
           } 


     }
```

Comment: once you close the app just resetAcesstoken, so that another user can logged in

Comment: I'm using Oaut authenticating with twitter app containing accessToken and consumerKey my account, then when you open the app it automatically logged into my account to download my user_timeline, I want to give users the ability to read my tweets and post some on your behalf if want .... understand? I wonder how other User login to post the tweet on your behalf and not on my